# Implementing AngularJS non-interrupting UI popup messages

Tags: angularjs, service, directive

I'm about to develop UI messaging system that displays info/warning/error messages in UI. I've developed a similar thing in jQuery, but now I'm about to do it for AngularJS.

Messaging works as simple as displaying a fixed positioned message at some screen position and remains displayed for some time (depending on content length calculated using minimum time + per word time) adn then automatically disappears from view.

Info and warning messages disappear automatically while errors need to be explicitly closed by user mouse click so we ensure they see them (actually they also get auto closed after a much **much** longer time to unblock message queue).

This messaging system also takes care of message queueing as only one message gets displayed at a time. This queue works as FIFO unless an error message comes in. Error messages are pushed into the queue as LIFO as they're much more important.

Anyway. I was thinking of doing this in two parts:

1. AngularJS Service that would implement message queueing and emitting events to $rootScope for individual messages.
2. AngularJS directive that displays the emitted message to the user.

### Question

As jQuery plugin this was all contained in that particular plugin but here I have to separate both parts, so controllers/services (i.e. interceptors) will be able to use this messaging. They would all use service, but directive will only be responsible for the actual display of these messages.

Now. What goes into each part? I have three possibilities:

1. Service implements queuing, directive implements timings
   **Problem** when should service emit message displays if directive controls timings?
2. Service implements queueing and timings, directive only displays and hides messages as emitted by a combination of events from service
   **Problem** how do I implement error message hiding initiated by user if not by another message going back from directive to service?
3. Service only implements API for callers (like `messageService.Show(type, message)`, directive implements everything else - queueing, timings, showing/hiding
   **Problem** none envisioned

Third one seems to be most straight forward but in this case service doesn't really serve any particular purpose except emitting message events. In terms of a service and directive it should be more vice-a-versa. Service should be intelligent and directive should be dumb.

**How should I implement my service to actually have some functionality (smart messaging service) and a dumb directive that just consumes whatever service tells it to do?**

Comment: I'm sorry but after I read the first 3 words of the title: "Implementing AngularJS unobtrusive" I wasn't able to keep reading... It seems to me that AngularJS and unobtrusive are 2 words that can't go together. Good luck though!

Comment: Read the source code for modal service in angular ui http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. Here the $modal service controls directives that show dialog.

Comment: @Josep: Why is that? Unobtrusiveness is related to users, not libraries like AngularJS. :)

Comment: @RobertKoritnik my bad, I should have kept reading, in the old days unobtrusive was almost synonym of making the whole experience available for browsers that have JS disabled... :$ Actually, your question is quite interesting! +1 (I have to go to bed right now, but I will answer it in the next 12-16 hours)

Comment: @Josep: But you're correct about *unobtrusive* meaning. It could be understood either way. It is related to code, but also to how code works in terms of UI, so... I rephrased my question to use different terms.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik There is just one thing that I don't quite understand: What's exactly what it will be triggering these messages? Do they get triggered as a result of user actions (filling up a field of a form, scrolling to a certain point, hitting a button/link...)? Do they come from a remote server? Because when I started modeling this I imagined the service handling the events, but in your explanation it seems that you want the service to trigger them. ("AngularJS Service that would implement message queueing and emitting events to $rootScope for individual messages")

Comment: @josep yes service would emit events to inform directive to display messages. Service itself should not manipulate views in any way. That's up to directives. So instead of manipulating some scope (could as well be $rootScope) it seems much better to communicate via events. Because this by itself is a state when some event happens. Be it user or server initiated...

Answer (score 1):

I actually implemented something that's pretty near to what you want to do. Maybe these code snippets can help you. 
This is just a quick solution, not really tested, but it might give you the idea.

**Directive**

```
angular.module( 'app' )
  .directive( 'alerter', function ( $timeout, alert )
  {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/directives/alerter/alerter.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      link: function ( $scope )
      {
        $scope.alerts = alert.alerts;

        $scope.closeAlert = function ( index, actualElement )
        {
          alert.remove( index, actualElement );
        };

        $scope.$watchCollection( 'alerts', function ( newAlerts )
        {
          $timeout( function ()
            {
              $scope.closeAlert( newAlerts.length - 1, newAlerts[newAlerts.length - 1] );
            },
            10000 );
        } );
      }
    };
  } );
```

**Template** (using UI-Bootstraps Alert http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

```
<div class="row">
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">
    {{alert.msg}}
  </alert>
</div>
```

**Service**

```
angular.module( 'app' )
  .factory( 'alert', function ()
  {
    var alerts = [],
      _TYPES = {
        ERROR: 'danger',
        SUCCESS: 'success'
      };

    function add( type, message )
    {
      alerts.push( {type: type, msg: message} );
    }

    function remove( index, actualElement )
    {
      alerts.splice( index, 1 );
    }

    // Public API here
    return {
      alerts: alerts,
      TYPE: _TYPES,
      add: function ( type, message )
      {
        return add( type, message );
      },
      remove: function ( index)
      {
        return remove( index);
      }
    };
  } );
```

**How I'm adding alerts in a controller**

```
angular.module( 'app' )
  .controller( 'SomeCtrl', function ( $scope, alert)
  {
    ...
    $scope.showError = function() {
        alert.add( alert.TYPE.ERROR, 'An error occured!' );
    };
    ...
} );
```

Where ever I want to be able to show the alerts I'm adding the Directive:

```
<alterter></alerter>
```

Comment: Oh, when removing an alerts you should make sure you're really removing the rihgt one. Since it might've already been removed by the the user or the $timeout

Comment: your controller should reference `alert` service as well. I know... You just missed it...

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I missed that :( Edited it!

Comment: Although it works I don't think this is an ideal solution. One issue I see is that directive can directly manipulate service data (alerts that should be private to service) and second one is that `$watchCollection` is arguably slower than `$emit` on `$rootScope` as it doesn't do any propagation. It's true that your message queue will likely stay short... Hence *arguably*.

Comment: Performance-wise that's true, but I'd say it is negligible. What's the problem of the directive beeing able to manipulate service data?

Comment: Well services are encapsulated features that expose API that manipulates inner data. In your case this data structure is exposed and can be manipulated making service code buggy/unusable. In your case code would become buggy if you'd assign whatever to `alert.alerts` like `null` or any primitive value, your service would stop working.

Comment: Well, yes. You'll always find a way to make things stop working. I'm not seeing any problems with just naming it _alerts, or whatever to mark it as "private" / "shouldn't be manipulated".

Comment: Well you can always make it private and since you need to access these item in your directive template you could expose them via a function `getAll()` or something. This way you would preserve them private in service's function scope and outside consumers wouldn't be able to manipulate them in any way. But that's of course just a suggestion from somebody that does code reviews as well.

Comment: Yea, that's the approach I'm actually using in my code. +1